# Any possibilities that makefile can use different compilers by flag and find variable gcc paths?

Tags: c, linux, makefile

Are there any possibilities that makefile can use different compilers by flag and find variable gcc paths? System is Linux.

So the goal should be anything like to say in command line "make CC=..." and it should use one of two possible compilers and should find the path to the second one (first compiler is standard gcc) in a way kind of "automatically". Is this possible?

For example:

First compiler:

```
CC := gcc
```

Second compiler first path:

```
CC := /path-to-compiler-1/gcc
```

Second compiler second path:

```
CC := /path-to-compiler-2/gcc
```

Unfortunately I have no clue how to realize that in an elegant way.

Edit:
The background about the two different compilers is, that the first is the standard linux gcc and the second for mips optimized gcc. So I just want to compile in both ways, compiling for mips on embedded site and standard compilation on normal linux site if necessary. Or another possiblity would be to compile both executables at the same time. The mips compiler is listed under a path that begins in all cases with /home/user. Thereby the folder user is variable and maybe there is another superordinate folder. Concerning this the makefile should find the right path for to the mips gcc.

Comment: So exactly how should the compiler be chosen, if both are there?

Comment: Are compiler paths knowm and fixed, or in system `PATH`, or how are the different places to look in determined?

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. The background about the two different compilers is, that the first is the standard linux gcc and the second for mips optimized gcc. So I just want to compile in both ways, compiling for mips and standard compilation if necessary. Or another possiblity would be to compile both executables at the same time. Yes, something like whereis sounds good. Normally the path should be beginn infact in all cases with /home/user. The folder user is variable and maybe another superordinate folder.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add all requirements and background information to the quesion instead of using comments for this purpose. How do you want to search for the compiler? Is there a list of possible paths? in `PATH`? How do you distinguish between the two compilers?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Done. Yes, possible paths are normally beginning with /home/user/, whereat user is variable and continue with a piece of path that should be exactly the same and ending with gcc. Only between /home/user/... -> and /same path/gcc could be a superordinate folder that should be considered.

Comment: Commonly additional compilers are installed in a way that you can call them directly without any path, in your case for example "mips-xxx-gcc". This command would be a symbolic link to the actual executable "/any-path-to-mips-installation/gcc". This way you would only need to provide the correct name, no need to fiddle with paths. At least this is the way I'm used to, and I expect it to some degree if I install for example a cross-compiler.

Comment: Ah thanks a lot, this sounds like the right way. So I have to find out how to create a kind of environment variable as a symbolic link to the real path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
CC = $(if $(COMPILER),$(COMPILER),gcc)
CFLAGS = -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall

all:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o demo demo.c

clean:
    rm -f demo
```

You can launch your `Makefile` with:

```
make COMPILER=gcc
```

or with

```
make COMPILER=clang
```

and if you don't provide any argument

```
make
```

the default is `gcc`

Comment: Yes, exactly something like this. Thanks a lot. Only the different paths of the not standard gcc (see above (new answer within first post)) has to be identify in kind of "automatically".

Comment: @Kerberos The default compiler on unixes is `cc`, do you mean this by "automatically"?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Sorry, I have edited my question by adding some more information about the scenario. The makefile should use an optimized mips compiler or, if necessary, the standard unix/linux compiler. And the mips compiler should be found by path whereat the path is lightly variable.

Comment: Just a briefly question @David Ranieri: Could it be just "CC = $(if $(COMPILER),$(COMPILER)) too without the "...,gcc)" entry? So that has to be typing into the console "make COMPILER=gcc" or "make COMPILER=xyz" or which function does the entry "...,gcc)" has additionally?

Comment: Yes, you can omit the `else` part but then you can not ommit the argument (you can not use plain `make`)

Comment: Ah okay, thanks! The 3 entries are like a if..elseif...else combination. Means COMPILER=x or COMPILER=y and if no COMPILER add on given in the console statement (simply make), than its the else branch and the normal gcc?

Comment: Yes, that is!!!